# PHP / Zend Mechanisms for Rewriting

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting

Hey there, this is a newbie Zend question. Under a site location: “**mydomain.org/subA/subB**”, if we go to this location without logging in (or having a session), it i) redirects to a login page. Otherwise, it ii) redirects to a race registration form. Now, I’d thought that Apache rewrite rules did that, but there’s not config that indicates that in our project .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

The only mechanisms I know that can do this sort of rewriting are i) Apache's mod_rewrite or ii) rewriting through Zend's controller or router components. Is there anything else I could be missing? Like I said I'm a PHP/Zend newbie, so it'd be nice to have something that can trace that request to see which systems it passes through.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would use Zend's built-in routing libraries:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Zend's router allows you to create re-written routes from within your application, without writing custom mod_rewrite rules. The rewrite rules you pasted from your .htaccess file is what Zend requires to do its job.

EDIT: I read your question a little more closely. I think you understand that Zend has routes. If you're looking for the reason the redirect is working, try checking the controller for the page that needs to authenticate. If `preDispatch()` is defined in the controller, it may be checking for session authentication and redirecting to a different controller if it's missing.

Comment: I'm confused. Was your question addressing an existing application, or one you were writing? Are you asking how Zend routes work or how to use authentication in the framework?

Comment: Hey there, I've got it working. I was referring to an existing (private) application I am working on, and I'd been through Zend's Controller and Router documentation. It turns out I had to tweak an Zend_Acl object through allow() and deny() methods. It was very tricky as I wasn't expecting a redirect as a kind of post-process decision. Makes sense in retrospect though. 

Hope that was clear. Thanks for all the feedback.